# How can I split array elements in arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

For example consider following array:

```
var array = [1,[2,3],5]
```

I want result in following way:

```
a = [1]
b = [2,3]
c = [5]
```

Comment: Why would you use such arrays? What problems are you trying to address?

Comment: Do you want each object as individual array like if array would have `[1,[2,3],5,6,7]` then `a=[1]`,`b=[2,3]`,`c=[5]`,`d=[6]`,`e=[7]`, or `c=[5,6,7]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split an array into chunks:

If you have an array of elements and you want to split them into chunks of a size you specify.
Example:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}

let numbers = Array(1...100)
let result = numbers.chunked(into: 5)
```

Now you can access first second and your index object from the result like:

```
let a = result.first // [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1,[2,3],5]
let a = [array[0]]
let b = [array[1]]
let c = [array[2]]
```

Comment: `let b = [array[1]]` will give you `[[2, 3]]`, not `[2, 3]`.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.